# Github all of the sudden says "fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Tags: git, github

All of the sudden github has started saying `fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` for me and my team when trying to push to or pull from one specific repository.

This was working until this morning and all of the sudden broke. So I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with our SSH keys. Github status says `All systems operational`.

We can access all of our repositories except for this one (and can still view it via the web interface).

What should we try to debug the issue?

Comment: Contact github support. If in fact this issue just happened out of the blue, this isn't an issue anyone else can help you with.

Comment: What are you doing to make this message appear (ie. which command are you issuing) ?

Comment: @GuillaumeA - it's on simple things, even trying to clone the repository fresh with `git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git tmprepodir` produces the error.

Comment: Does it happen only with your repository? Try to clone another repo, e.g. a public one.

Comment: Are you sure it’s not your SSH key? Do you use an SSH agent which is possibly not running now? Also, are you sure the address to the repository is correct (case-sensitive)?

Comment: @Amiramix - yes, we can even clone other private github repos owned by this account. Is there a repo-specific setting that could be affecting this?

Comment: https://status.github.com/

Comment: Got the same error after running: `git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git`, tried it again with `git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git` and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 16:13 UTC: Investigating SSH access problems on one fileserver pair
>
> 16:26 UTC: Everything operating normally.

[GitHub status](https://status.github.com).

So yeah, this is a temporary issue, just give it a bit time. *Edit: It should be fixed now.*

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly encounter the same. Possibly an emerging issue.

As a test, I verified my SSH key authentication with the following command at the Terminal and received a successful response:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I contacted GitHub with details of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been a transient issue with github. It has now started working just as mysteriously as it stopped.